# Found Any required Int and unreachable code in pattern matching

Tags: scala

I'm making the following function in Scala that returns the largest element in a list of integers:

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
    case head :: Nil => head
    case head :: tail => {
      val maxTail = max(xs.tail)
      if(xs.head > maxTail) xs.head else maxTail
    }
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
  }
```

And I have the following error:

Found: (head : Any) Required: Int  The following import might make progress towards fixing the problem:  import munit.Clue.generate

Which doesn't make any sense. And if I try this:

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
    case (head: Int) :: Nil => head
    case (head: Int) :: tail => {
      val maxTail = max(xs.tail)
      if(xs.head > maxTail) xs.head else maxTail
    }
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
  }
```

the error is

this case is unreachable since type java.util.List[Int] and class :: are unrelated

for the first case.

I think something in my configuration is broken. To use xs.head I had to use

```
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversions.*
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversionsToScala.*
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vR8wrGpxQoO7RB9awJ43YA)

Comment: Can you share your input list?

Comment: Your code works for me too. `List[Int]` is a Scala type so your problem seems to be on your input list. 
Anyway, you could do `yourList.max` to get the max element of an Integer list

Comment: Also note that you already have `head` and `tail` in the second case, so no need to extract them from `xs` again.

Comment: It looks likely you have something like `import java.util.List` which should be removed.

Comment: @JavierMontón yes, but the excercise is to implement max function for lists.

Comment: @Tim thanks, I didn't notice that

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I don't. I only have: import java.util.*
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversions.*
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversionsToScala.*

Comment: @TomerShetah I type "console" in sbt to watch the errors.

Comment: `import java.util.*` is exactly the problem. If you remove it, `List` will be the Scala type which already has `head` and `tail`, so you won't need the other two `import`s either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AlexeyRomanov notes, you likely have an `import java.util.List` which is shadowing the compiler-injected (thus lower priority) `import scala._` (which would pull in `scala.List` which is a type alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`).  When importing `java.util.List` it's generally a good practice to rename the import in some way.

```scala
import java.util.{ List => JList }  // fairly common renaming

// alternatively, you can rename java.util
import java.{ util => JU }         // java.util.List can now be JU.List
```

It's possible, that your Scala compiler options include `-Yno-imports`, which disables the compiler-injected imports:

```scala
import java.lang._
import scala._
import scala.Predef._
```

In this scenario, perhaps you didn't mean to import `java.util.List`, in which case (assuming that your project has `-Yno-imports` for a reason) an explicit import of `scala.List` instead of `java.util.List` is called for:

```scala
import scala.List
```

Comment: It occurs to me that one common scenario for `-Yno-imports` might be in an educational project where the assignment is reimplementing `scala.List`, in which case you may want to double check the assignment and also beware that IDE hints for the (for want of a better term) "enlightened" may be counterproductive.

Comment: I had theese imports: ```import java.util.*
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversions.*
import collection.convert.ImplicitConversionsToScala.*``` I added import scala.List and it worked. Which one should I keep? Also, refering to your comment, the assignment specifies to use head and tail, so the imports must let me use them.